# Finding $\frac{dy}{dx}$ given $y= \frac{ \sin x + x^2 }{ \cot 2x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am unable to differentiate the following:

> Given  $\;y= \dfrac{ \sin x + x^2 }{ \cot 2x},\;$ find $\;\dfrac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: what is the downvote for?

Comment: People do not like if you just say "please help". People want to see what you have tried, and in which context you have encountered this problem. By the way, I did not downvote.

Comment: Do you remember how to compute the derivative of $u(x)/v(x)$ and the derivative of $a(x)+b(x)$ ? Giving you the answer is not in your interest. Tell what you did and where you are stuck.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici , I tried that formula, but the answer is too weird and not compact

Comment: Add what you did to your post, please.

Comment: Have you tried looking for any trig identities to help you? I would bet that there is some trig identity that makes this problem quite easy/simple.

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{ \sin x + x^2 }{ \cot 2x}\right)=2(x^2+\sin x)\sec^22x+(2x+\cos x)\tan2x$$

Comment: “Dont give a child a fish but show him how to fish”

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** the Quotient Rule is $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac uv=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}$

Using the Quotient Rule and $\cot(x)=\frac1{\tan(x)}$ along with the usual derivatives of the trig functions should help.

Answer (score 0):

you have $y=(\sin x+x^2)\tan 2x$, then
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(\sin x+x^2)\cdot\tan2x+(\sin x+x^2)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\tan2x\\
=(\cos x+2x)\tan2x+(\sin x+x^2)\frac{1}{\cos^22x}\cdot 2$$

then you simplify it.